# Dyanmic JTable creation, how do I know which table is it?

Tags: java, jtable, dynamic-controls

I have this code that I need to run depending on a number. I thought it was easy and YES it was but then this brick wall hit me...

how do I know which table am I clicking at or which table to put items into???

```
private void createTablesForBuilding() {
    int buildingcoutns = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < buildingcoutns; i++) {
        JTable jt = new JTable();

        tables.add(jt);
        tables.get(i).setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][]{
                    {null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null}
                },
                new String[]{
                    "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
                }
        ));

        tables.get(i).getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if (jt.getSelectedRow() > -1) {
                    System.out.print("what now???");
                }
            }
        });

        JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane();
        js.setViewportView(tables.get(i));

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jp.add(js);

        Buildings_Panel.add(jp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it!. I created a separate class and assigned a variable inside it where I can put a an ID to my table. this is what I did.

```
private void createTablesForBuilding() {
    int buildingcoutns = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < buildingcoutns; i++) {
        myTables tbls = new myTables();
        tbls.setTableID(i);

        tables.add(tbls);

        JTable thistable = tables.get(i).table;

        thistable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][]{
                    {null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null}
                },
                new String[]{
                    "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
                }
        ));

        tables.get(i).table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if (thistable.getSelectedRow() > -1) {
                    System.out.println("tableID is:"+tbls.getTableID());
                }
            }
        });

        Buildings_Panel.add(tables.get(i));
    }
}
```

and here is myTables

```
public class myTables extends javax.swing.JPanel {

int tableID = 0;

public myTables() {
    initComponents();
}

public void setTableID(int i){
    tableID = i;
}
public int getTableID(){
    return tableID;
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    table = new javax.swing.JTable();

    setLayout(new java.awt.CardLayout());

    table.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(table);

    add(jScrollPane1, "card2");
}// </editor-fold>                        


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
public javax.swing.JTable table;
// End of variables declaration
```

}